# Google Maps/Remove markers in backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am a new user of JS and backbone.js.

I have a backbone app that is making requests to Google Maps api, and is successfully dropping pins based on a search in the app.

Now, I would like to remove the old markers from the map when search is executed for new markers.

Here is my addMarker function :

```
function addmarker(model) {
  var self = this,
    marker;

  _geocode.call(this, model.get('address'))
    .done(function(location) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        map: self.map,
        position: location
      });

  _infowindow.call(self, marker, model);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("This address cannot be retrieved from the server");
    });

};
```

I would like to remove the old markers at the beginning of this function call.  I tried storing the markers in an array and calling the setMap(null) function on each element with a clearMarkers function per the API documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

This did not work.

What is the most efficient way to remove markers in this context?

Let me know if you have questions about the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a global array of markers and push each marker to it. For example:

```
var markers = [];
```

then in `addMarker()` function:

```
markers.push(marker); // where marker is your google.Maps.Marker();
```

So if you want to remove all markers:

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Wrap this in a function and/or call it first in your `addMarker()` function.